# Making a query result table (GUI) using Java

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a panel where the user will search for a customer by entering a surname or ID. I want to implement some kind of table that displays each row of SQL query results. What's the best way to do this? The first thing that comes to my mind would be to use a multi-dimensional array and a JTextArea. What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into a JTable?

Edit: This is my first time replying so I guess I'll notice when I do something wrong. I have recently created something similar to what you are aiming for, so this piece of code might set you on your way:

```
String[][] results = null;
    if(query != null){
        results = domeinController.Search(query);
    } else {
        results = domeinController.ReturnAllAccounts();
        txtSearch.setText("");
    }
    TableModel table = new DefaultTableModel(results, new String[] {d("LBL_SERVICE"), d("LBL_ACC_NAME"), d("LBL_PASSWORD"), d("LBL_EMAIL")});
    tblResults = new JTable(){
        public boolean isCellEditable(int roxIndex, int colIndex){
            return false;
        }
    };      
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tblResults);
    tblResults.setModel(table);
    tblResults.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    tblResults.setBounds(55, 145, 423, 228);
    tblResults.getTableHeader().setAutoscrolls(true);
    tblResults.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    tblResults.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);
    tblResults.setShowVerticalLines(false);
    tblResults.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
            tblResultsMousePressed(evt);
        }
    });
```

Basically you create a tableModel with a 2D Array of data as your 1st parameter, and an array with headers for your 2nd parameter. After that you can specify behaviour to your table.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend taking [Glazed List](http://www.glazedlists.com/) into account.

It's a library which takes care of the most of the heavylifting related to presenting tabular data in a table with both filtering and sorting. It also provides a multithreading-safe datamodel. Using bare Swing and Java it's a lot lot harder to implement it all correctly.

[Here](http://www.glazedlists.com/documentation/tutorial-100) is a nice tutorial provided. Once anybody starts writing CRUD GUIs, sooner or later all end up wanting so called "standard features" which all table oriented guis share in common. Why wasting time inventing it all and risking making a lot of mistakes, when you can build upon proven solutions. Especially, when it's so easy.

An example, displaying a XML based JTable:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.Insets;
// a simple issues library
import ca.odell.issuezilla.*;
// glazed lists
import ca.odell.glazedlists.*;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.swing.*;
/**
 * An IssueBrowser is a program for finding and viewing issues.
 * 
 * @author <href="mailto:jesse@odel.on.ca">Jesse Wilson</a>
 */
public class IssuesBrowser {

 /** event list that hosts the issues */
 private EventList issuesEventList = new BasicEventList();

 /**
  * Create an IssueBrowser for the specified issues.
  */
 public IssuesBrowser(Collection issues) {
   issuesEventList.addAll(issues);
 }

 /**
  * Display a frame for browsing issues.
  */
 public void display() {
   // create a panel with a table
   JPanel panel = new JPanel();
   panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
   EventListModel issuesListModel = new EventListModel(issuesEventList);
   JList issuesJList = new JList(issuesListModel);
   JScrollPane issuesListScrollPane = new JScrollPane(issuesJList);
   panel.add(issuesListScrollPane, new GridBagConstraints(...));

   // create a frame with that panel
   JFrame frame = new JFrame("Issues");
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   frame.setSize(540, 380);
   frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
   frame.show();
 }

 /**
  * Launch the IssuesBrowser from the commandline.
  */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   if(args.length != 1) {
     System.out.println("Usage: IssuesBrowser <file>");
     return;
   }

   // load some issues
   Collection issues = null;
   try {
     IssuezillaXMLParser parser = new IssuezillaXMLParser();
     InputStream issuesInStream = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
     issues = parser.loadIssues(issuesInStream, null);
     issuesInStream.close();
   } catch(IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     return;
   }
   // create the browser
   IssuesBrowser browser = new IssuesBrowser(issues);
   browser.display();
 }
}
```

Comment: ..why? Please provide an excerpt and/or reasoning.